# Strange reputation behaviour

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting, voting-fraud

I've [contacted Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/contact?referrer=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fhelp%2fserial-voting-reversed) a couple of times about this, and there have been [automated voting corrections](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) to my reputation, but I seem to have had reputation increases on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45834103/1945782) that don't really reflect the quality of my answer, again.

I'm worried that these increases are more destructive (though intended as an obvious reward, it destabilises the quality of SO) than reflective of the question/answer quality.

The up-voter was suspended for a week, but would this stop them creating new accounts and performing similar up-votes?

I've also noticed odd voting behaviour on another site, though this is a little less obvious at the moment.

Do I need to worry about this?

Comment: Having a "fan" isn't really something you need to worry about. Their voting patterns aren't your fault, and the system handles this type of stuff without breaking a sweat. (Unless their voting patterns *are* your fault, then tell them to stop. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray: [I did tell them to stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45834103/how-to-check-for-the-previous-path-searched-on-a-maze-c-sharp/45835277#comment79025460_45834103)! ;o)

Comment: @CodyGray - Quote: *Having a "fan" isn't really something you need to worry about* - have you seen [Misery](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100157/?ref_=nv_sr_1)?!!

Comment: @CodyGray Generally correct, but having "-xyz points: Voting corrected" in your rep history is kind of a bad mark and I already saw a few users (very few to be honest) who used that to claim that user had a sock puppet to vote for themself :/.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> The up-voter was suspended for a week, but would this stop them creating new accounts and performing similar up-votes?

I'm not going to go into details, but we have measures in place to prevent this kind of abuse.

If you notice more such strange voting patterns in the future, feel free to flag, though. Moderators are always happy to step in.

> I've also noticed odd voting behaviour on another site, though this is a little less obvious at the moment.

Perhaps flag a related post on that site and let the moderators there know. They can investigate.

Moderators have the tools to see far more details, including voting and access patterns.